# Matplotlib plot barplots-stacked in a loop in different positions on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a list of dictionaries that have different keys and a different number of keys.

```
users_records = [{'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.5}, {'c': 0.3, 'd': 0.2, 'e': 0.5}, {'f': 1.0}]
```

I want to plot these elements in this list (dictionary), each element as a stacked bar plot. I could plot a single dictionary using the following code.
I expected something like this
[image]

```
for user in users_records:
 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.Series(user)).T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

But every bar is plotted in the same location in the plot. How can I shift the bars on x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(users_records).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]